# MVC4 Project - cannot DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 internet application using forms authentication.

Out of the box the `UserProfile` model is created in the Account models file, I have moved that to its own file and called `DbSet<UserProfile`> in my `DbContext` file. I expected EF to create a 2 table database, UserProfiles and Stories.

```
public class MySocialStoriesDb : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Story> Stories { get; set; }
}
```

Story Model

```
[Table("Stories")]
public class Story
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int StoryId { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }

    public string File { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

UserProfile Model

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string UserDirectory { get; set; }
    public bool Paid { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePaid { get; set; }
    public string PaymentId { get; set; }
}
```

I have run Enable-Migrations from Package Manager and allowed automatic migrations and allowed dataloss. The InitialCreate file generated only seems to create the User Profile table, it doesn't have anything in its code for the Story table.

I added the following line to Global.asax

```
Database.SetInitializer(new Models.IntializeMySocialStoriesDb());
```

If i now change a model nothing on the database changes. If i manually drop the database and change the `InitializeMySocialStoriesDb` to DropCreateDatabaseAlways and then run the app, the database is not created.

I am just wondering what I have missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother with this mechanism. It's not feasible for production apps and requires you to hose all your data each time the schema changes.

Instead create your database schema as a separate SSDT project and use DACPAC files to initially deploy and upgrade your production database while keeping all the data intact. Just copy the tables that SimpleMembership creates into your SSDT project.

This way you have exact column definitions, can exactly define constraints, exactly define foreign keys, primary keys and unique keys etc. and still access your data through Entity Framework in your application project. Upgrading the schema on the production database simply requires a DACPAC to be deployed.

During development, Visual Studio will automatically make any changes to the table structure when you make changes in SSDT.

In short I think code-first is too loosely defined, unorganised and a bad idea.

Comment: I wanted to use EF to generate all of my table structures during dev. So if things change, fields get added etc during the intial development process the tables change too. Until it becomes live the data is junk anyway.

Comment: Visual Studio will still automatically create and change table structures when you debug the app. You add the new field (column) in SSDT and just refresh your EDMX. The table structure will change automatically while still retianing data. The SSDT project is also under source control so the schema is also version controlled.

Comment: I will do a quick bit of reading on SQL Server Database Projects in VS (If it is just a edmx in a seperate project maybe not much to learn). I have used code-first in another project without problems, still interested to see what went wrong with using it this time too.

Comment: SSDT simply stores your entire database definition as plain SQL files in another project. Each time you debug, it pushes the changes (if any) to the database and then launches your app. If you want to add a field, just add the column in SSDT, click debug once to update the database, then refresh your EDMX. The level of control your have over the schema with SSDT is a huge advantage over code first. For production schema upgrades you simply export a DACPAC from SSDT instead of relying on the app to upgrade the database. The DACPAC deployment warns you of any potential data loss etc.

Comment: Although this doesn't help fix the code-first issue, having looked into SSDT a little (also watched: http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/SQL11UPD00-REC-02) I like it and agree it is a better approach than code first. Thanks for pointing out the SSDT stuff!

Comment: Without code first, you lose the ability to extend your data model classes. You should use the MVVM pattern to expose data models in through view models. You can freely extend the view models.

Comment: Can you post a link or something to expand on that? From what I read today using SSDT instead of code-first you just create models from EF, using DB first. So you dont lose functionality, except models need to be updated when you change db project. But you gain versioning and rock solid DB schema updates in production.

Comment: You can't modify the EDMX generated classes unlike code first. You can extend them to some extent with partial classes but not completely customise them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28783/discussion-between-james-and-kurian)