# Manually Synchronising Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I am looking to migrate my Linq2Sql project to Entity Framework (v5.0).

The EF Code is in a separate class library called from a MVC4 web application.

I am using 'code-first' with an existing database.

For various reasons, I want/need to be able to manage updates to either the SQL tables or the EF models manually.

It seems that I need to be able to make EF *aware* of any such changes, but I am not sure of the correct methods for achieving this.

I have read that EF is using a tracking table (__MigrationHistory ?) that you can manually delete to force a rebuild of the EF metadata, but I can't see this table anywhere in the target SQL database.

I have also read about EF Migrations, but I am not sure that they are what I am looking for in this scenario.

Any advice/direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend you look at my answer here first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167567/mvc4-project-cannot-dropcreatedatabaseifmodelchanges/16167688#16167688

Comment: Thanks Kurian, The SSID and DACPAC method seem a much better production solution and also improves the general management of the SQL database - thank you.  I still have one question though, how to I refresh the Entity Framework model to reflect these changes.  I have found references to a .edmx file but this doesn't appear to exist in my project (I'm guessing because I am using code-first)?

Comment: You shouldn't use code-first at all. Create the SSDT project and run it to create the database. Then create a database-first EDMX from the instance "(localdb)\Projects" and the database name. When you change the database schema in the SSDT project just run it once to update the schema in the localdb database, then refresh your EDMX from the database. During development, your project should connect to the localdb database on your computer, instead of a common SQL Server database.

Comment: Thank you Kurian.  I was initially trying to create a Data Access Layer that was not dependent upon any framework - hence the code-first POCO route, but I guess everything is a compromise and this approach certainly seems to have a lot less overhead.  I have 1+ your other answer as I feel this answers my question.  Thanks again for your time and explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kurian's comment was helpful in defining a better approach - see their original response to a similar question at [MVC4 Project - cannot DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167567/mvc4-project-cannot-dropcreatedatabaseifmodelchanges/16167688#16167688)